# Why does Azure Content Moderator fail to detect custom terms?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to detect [*custom*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/content-moderator/try-terms-list-api) flagged keywords in a chunk of text, using Azure Cognitive services (more specifically `azure-cognitiveservices-vision-contentmoderator==1.0.0`).

Code runs as follows:

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.contentmoderator import ContentModeratorClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

subscription_key = '<my_key>'
endpoint_url = 'https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/'

client = ContentModeratorClient(endpoint_url, CognitiveServicesCredentials(subscription_key))
```

Afterwards, I am also able to create a list (named `123`) of custom terms (using the methods `client.list_management_term_lists.create` and `client.list_management_term.add_term`)

```
client.list_management_term_lists.create(
        content_type="application/json",
        body={
            "name": "My custom list",
            "description": "Monty Python related terms",
        }
)

client.list_management_term.add_term(
        list_id=123,
        term="eggs",
        language="eng"
)
```

and I can verify that this is working as intended as

```
terms_data = client.list_management_term.get_all_terms(list_id=123, language="eng").data
terms_data.as_dict()
```

yields

> {'language': 'eng',  'terms': [{'term': 'eggs'}, {'term': 'spam'}], 
>   'status': {'code': 3000, 'description': 'OK'},  'tracking_id':
>   'some_id'}

However, if I attempt detection with

```
import io

TEXT = "Do you like spam and eggs ?"

text_screen = client.text_moderation.screen_text(
    text_content_type="text/plain",
    text_content=io.StringIO(TEXT),
    language="eng",
    list_id=123,
    classify=True
)

text_screen.as_dict()
```

no `'Terms'` entity appears, as what I get from the above is just:

> ```
> {'original_text': 'Do you like spam and eggs ?',
>  'normalized_text': ' you like spam  eggs ?',
>  'classification': {'category1': {'score': 0.028309470042586327},
>   'category2': {'score': 0.14004242420196533},
>   'category3': {'score': 0.12679287791252136},
>   'review_recommended': False},
>  'status': {'code': 3000, 'description': 'OK'},
>  'language': 'eng'}
> ```

What am I doing wrong and how should I do it properly?

Also (not sure if relevant), firing

```
client.list_management_term_lists.refresh_index_method(list_id=123, language="eng")
```

yields me an `APIErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Not Found'`

Comment: It could be that this is related to a bug... I thus filed https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-python-sdk-samples/issues/54

Comment: Do you able to fix this? In my case i have custom terms more than 100. But its only checking first 50 terms.